# Create and Download Zip File is printing garbage value on the screen

Tags: php, file-io, zip

It is a follow up question to my previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350947/php-readfile-printing-garbage-value-on-the-screen

I am creating a PHP file and then trying to download it.

What's happening is, When I create and then download, it prints garbage value on the screen.

However, If I just download the same zip file, it works perfectly fine.

My guess is, that the zip file might not be created when it tries to download it ?

Can you please suggest me, where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: [PHP readfile printing garbage value on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350947/php-readfile-printing-garbage-value-on-the-screen) is also asking about "garbage being printed to the screen", so I don't understand what makes this a "follow up" rather then a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it is a followup, it is not related to PHP readfile at all. So, that makes it a followup. I have mentioned readfile is working properly.

Comment: If it isn't a duplicate, you need to edit the question and post your current code. And you should also clarify whether "garbage" means that you're getting the ZIP contents printed ("PK...") or something totally unrelated.